# Difference between assets and res/raw

Tags: android, directory, directory-structure

I wanted to be clear on the difference between the `assets` and `res/raw`
directories. Presumably I can put anything in assets without bloating
my application whereas `res/raw` becomes bundled in the application and
directly accessible from within the Android application source code,
unlike say, sample images and shell scripts which I can bundle with
the project source code in a zip file after placing them under the
assets directory. Could someone kindly confirm my understanding
of these two directories?

Thanks,

Jason Posit